# Location of the svn repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, location

I have to add a file in a project in the svn repository. What is the best method to add a file? And I have to run that file through command line and for that I need the location of the svn repository. How do I find the location of the SVN repository? I tried svn info and I got an error stating '.' is not a working copy.

The Problem is, the ones who installed the svn are not available. And I need to know the location of the repository to run a file through the command line.

Much thanks.

Comment: Subclipse is the plugin used

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask your fellow developers or repository administrator what your repository location is. You should already have the project checked out, in which case you are already using a working copy that is linked to it and you don't need to do any more to point at the right location.

As for how to add an item, that will depend on what client you're using. In Subclipse, it's Team -> Add. In TortoiseSVN, it's TortoiseSVN -> Add. On the command line, it's `svn add <filename>`

It sounds like you have no experience with Subversion. You would do well to [read the fine manual](http://svnbook.org/) before you get yourself into trouble.